# session value stored is displayed only after I refresh page

Tags: php

I am trying to display the username and other session values stored in session at login.php. I post the form in index.php using ajax post which is in script.js. The session is stored but I can retrieve the value only after I refresh the page.
Can anyone please help me sort this issue.

My index.php file

```
<div id="profile">
    <?php session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && $_SESSION['user_name'] != ''){
        echo "Hello ".$_SESSION['user_name'];
        ?>
        <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

My script.js file

```
success: function(html){
  if(html=='true'){
    $("#login_form").fadeOut("normal");
    $("#profile").html("<a href='logout.php' class='red' id='logout'>Logout</a>");
}
```

My login.php

```
echo 'true';
$_SESSION['user_name']='username';
```

Comment: You are storing the session values in login.php but using ajax to get data. I am not able to understand the flow can you provide the code of login.php so it can be more helpful to understand

Comment: I am currently storing static value at the moment

Comment: Can you provide more code so that it can be more understandable

Comment: post your Ajax code